# Unable to install gitlab with chef on rhel7

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

My recipe is working well until it starts to install. I don't know why it was unable to run the system reconfigure command using `bash` resource.

Is there any other way to run the command

```rb
bash 'reconfigure gitlab' do
  code <<-EOH
    gitlab-ctl reconfigure
  EOH
end
```

Is there any other way to run this command other than `execute` resource?

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.18.31
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab-setup", "firewalld"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - gitlab-setup (0.1.0)
  - firewalld (1.1.5)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 12 resources
Recipe: gitlab-setup::default
  * yum_package[curl] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[openssh-server] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[postfix] action install (up to date)
  * service[sshd] action enable (up to date)
  * service[sshd] action start (up to date)
  * service[postfix] action enable (up to date)
  * service[postfix] action start (up to date)
  * firewalld_port[80/tcp] action add
    * execute[add port 80/tcp to zone] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * firewalld_port[443/tcp] action add
    * execute[add port 443/tcp to zone] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * yum_repository[gitlab_gitlab-ce] action create
    * template[/etc/yum.repos.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.repo] action create (up to date)
    * execute[yum clean metadata gitlab_gitlab-ce] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    * execute[yum-makecache-gitlab_gitlab-ce] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    * ruby_block[yum-cache-reload-gitlab_gitlab-ce] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
     (up to date)
  * yum_package[gitlab-ce] action install (up to date)
  * bash[reconfigure gitlab] action run

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[reconfigure gitlab]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170129-29430-hbdnfx" ----
    STDOUT:
    STDERR:
    ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170129-29430-hbdnfx" ----
    Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170129-29430-hbdnfx" returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/gitlab-setup/recipes/default.rb

     46: bash 'reconfigure gitlab' do
     47:   code <<-EOH
     48:      gitlab-ctl reconfigure
     49:   EOH
     50: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/gitlab-setup/recipes/default.rb:46:in `from_file'

    bash("reconfigure gitlab") do
      action [:run]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command "reconfigure gitlab"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      code "     gitlab-ctl reconfigure\n"
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "gitlab-setup"
      recipe_name "default"
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
```

Comment: Really hard to figure it out from the log output.. `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` seems to not emit anything (empty `STDOUT:` / `STDERR:`). Have you tried to run the command manually?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I run the command manually its working well but unable to run with resource bash and execute

Comment: Can you check the command's exit code when running manually? Chef assumes that it failed, if it returns non-zero exit code.

Comment: Might also want to look for a verbose mode flag

Comment: `execute 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure'` should do, no need for a bash resource here. But as gitlab is an omnibus install maybe there's clash from gitlab inner chef run.

Comment: Could also be a case where a non-zero exit code is actually acceptable, in which case you'd have to identify what the acceptable exit codes are and place them into an array for the `returns` property, i.e.
 `execute 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure' do
  return [0, 1337, 142]
end`
values provided are to show syntax only. They are not a claim that those are acceptable exit codes. https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#properties

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came to know that due to lack of memory in the instance the command gitlab-ctl reconfigure is unable to perform its action. two ways we can increase it like if we are using AWS instance then increase your instance type like from t2.micro to t2.large etc. Other way is like increase memory in kitchen.yml file by defining 
memory
4096